# How to get list of volume names from PVC list using ansible?

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

In my machines , 4 pvc are created. Now i need to get all volume name associated with the pvc in a list. Then those list will be passed to storage array and i will ensure that the volumes are created in storage server.

```
- name: Verify whether the PVC is created
    command: "kubectl get pvc pvc{{local_uuid}}-{{item}} -o json"
    with_sequence: start=1 end=4
    register: result

- set_fact: 
      pvcstatus: "{{ (item.stdout |from_json).status.phase }}"
      volume_name: "{{(item.stdout |from_json).spec.volumeName}}"
    with_items: "{{ result.results}}"

 - debug: var=volume_name
```

But when i run the above tasks , volume_name is having last volumename alone instead of all the volumes as a list. How to get all the volume names in a list?

Answer (score 1):

Your `set_fact` task is setting `volume_name` to a single value in each iteration...so of course, when the loop completes, the variable has the value from the final iteration. That's the expected behavior.  If you want a list, you need to create a list.  You can do this by *appending* to a list in your `set_fact` loop:

```
- set_fact: 
    volume_name: "{{ volume_name|default([]) + [(item.stdout |from_json).spec.volumeName] }}"
  with_items: "{{ result.results}}"
```

The expression `volume_name|default([])` will evaluate to an empty list when `volume_name` is undefined (which is the case on the first iteration of the loop).

I tested this out using the following playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    result:
      results:
        - stdout: '{"spec": {"volumeName": "volume1"}}'
        - stdout: '{"spec": {"volumeName": "volume2"}}'
        - stdout: '{"spec": {"volumeName": "volume3"}}'
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: result

    - set_fact: 
        volume_name: "{{ volume_name|default([]) + [(item.stdout |from_json).spec.volumeName] }}"
      with_items: "{{ result.results}}"

    - debug:
        var: volume_name
```

Which results in:

```
TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "volume_name": [
        "volume1",
        "volume2",
        "volume3"
    ]
}
```